# Google BigQuery: Cannot create transfer from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I try to use the Google Cloud Console to create a scheduled data transfer to Big Query from Google Cloud Storage but it keep prompting this error message.

```
Data source definition doesn't define this parameter Id: encoding
```

I tried to import the same csv file from Cloud Storage manually by using the `Add Data` function and it is working well, the data is imported to my existing table.

Tried `bq load` command also imported successfully.

Anyone encountered this issue before and is there any solution?

Comment: I would recommend to contact Google support or create a case as they can investigate your internal logs for this query: https://cloud.google.com/contact